# Undefined variable: files (View: \resources\views\home.blade.php)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I am trying to get some data (all filenames) from files table in dropdown but it gives error: Undefined variable: files

Controller:

```php
public function show($id)
{
   $data = File::findOrFail($id);
   $files = \DB::table('files')->get();

   return view('userhome', compact('data', 'files'));
}
```

Blade template:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="text-left">Select Record</label>
    <select name="parent_id">
          <option value="">Select Record</option>
          @foreach ($files as $filename)
              <option value="{{ $filename->id }}">{{ $files->filename }}</option>
          @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

web.php: https://ibb.co/xMswcTG

What causes this error?

Comment: You're using `compact('data', 'users')` to send data to your view. First of all the `users` variable doesn't exist in the context for your `show` method, so it can't be sent. Second, you should add `'files'` to that [compact](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) list for the `$files` variable to be available in the Blade view file. Also, for future reference, please don't use images instead of text like you did for you routes list, it makes for a better question.

Comment: ok i changed it but still same error

Comment: What line does the error occur on in your Blade file?

Comment: @Bogdan   https://ibb.co/dc0Ggx9   complete error

Comment: Hmm, that should work. Try clearing your compiled views by running `php artisan view:clear`.

Comment: cleared but nthing happens

Comment: Error is on your `home` view, and you are returning `userhome` from controller

Comment: if i write userhome or just home the error is same

Answer (score 3):

you return userhome.blade.php into your controller but try to get $files and $data variables into home.blade.php

change

```
return view('userhome', compact('data', 'files'));
```

to

```
return view('home', compact('data', 'files'));
```

all must be working ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use "$filename->" object instead of "$files->" object in options tag.
Please update the blade with below code.

```
 <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="text-left">Select Record</label>
                    <select name="parent_id">
                        <option value="">Select Record</option>
                        @foreach ($files as $filename)
                        <option value="{{ $filename->id }}">{{ $filename->filename }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
```